# PyInstaller Exe behaves differently to script

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

Aight so I'm getting a user input from a secondary window using customtkinter.

When running the script from MSCode everything works fine.

- The User inputs into the `CTkEntry` widget.
- The `textvariable` properly assigns value.
- This value is accessed elsewhere.

However, when I use `pyinstaller` to create an .exe of the same script, the `textvariable` simply stops assigning it's value to the `textvariable`

Can anyone point me to where/what may be cause an error such as this? 
Is it that these mods are not compatible?

As a side note: I am using `CTkEntry` in a similar manor with the main window and have had no such issues with it with identical syntax.

I'm using `auto-py-to-exe` with settings:

- One Directory
- Console Based (for dubugging)
- Locating the customTkinter lib folder
- `--hiddenimport win32timezone` (throws errors otherwise)

The window looks like:

```
self.entryString = tkinter.StringVar()
entryWidget = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=self.window, textvariable=self.entryString)
entryWidget.pack()
customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.window, text="Done", command=self.dismissWindow).pack()
```

Which is later accessed using:

```
self.entryString.get()
```

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: Calling the geometry manager on the same line is not advised because they all return `None`, you should move them to separate lines.  I see that you have `textvariabel=self.TempNew` and I would expect that to be an instance of `StringVar` since you are calling `self.entrystring.get()` why is it set to `self.TempNew`?

Comment: @Rory Ahh I didn't notice that in the question. I was changing it to different variables to see if it didn't like 'global' variables (`self.var = __` vs `var = __`) - I've fixed the code in the question. On that note, changing the `.pack()` to the line below did not solve the error, but I understand it's a better practice to have

Comment: @Alexander In my attempts to create a minimal reproducible example I could not replicate the same error, despite nearly word-for-word copying the script piece by piece. Nevertheless I did find the solution in the process as I've answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so to close the question I did find and solve my issue.

I have a root window `main`. Inside `main` I have a button that opens another window `form` for the user to interact with. `form` itself also opens new windows.

The windows created with `form` are `TkTopLevel` , as they should be (I'm under the impression one should avoid multiple root windows)

What I didn't realise was that `form` was a root window, and not a `TkTopLevel`.
So when I returned to `main`, the `textvariables` in `form` were not updating their values. I have no idea what *specifically* causes this error within the `Tk` library, but after changing `form` to a `TkTopLevel` the interactions worked as intended.